# gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out with Ubuntu Bionic

Tags: apt, gnupg

**Aim:**

I want to add apt-key to Ubuntu Bionic

**Environment:**

Ubuntu Bionic 18.04.3

**Command:**

`/usr/bin/apt-key adv --no-tty --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv E084DAB9`

or

`/usr/bin/apt-key adv --no-tty --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9`

**Error:**

"stderr": "Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)\ngpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out\n", "stderr_lines": ["Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)", "gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out"

**Additional Info:**

- This works fine for Ubuntu Xenial but does not work for Ubuntu Bionic.
- I am running this command inside Ubuntu Bionic docker container. I pulled this ubuntu bionic image on my local and executed `/usr/bin/apt-key adv --no-tty --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9`, that seems to be working fine.

```
/usr/bin/apt-key adv --no-tty --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.rA90EMTH3h/gpg.1.sh --no-tty --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
gpg: key 51716619E084DAB9: public key "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

However, `/usr/bin/apt-key adv --no-tty --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv E084DAB9` does not work and times out in Ubuntu Bionic docker container.

Anybody facing similar issue? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!